# How can I programmatically segue with tapping on an Image?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I've implemented 2 ImageViews with images and tapGestures, this works fine, now I want to segue to another ViewController dependent on which image I've tapped. I don't know how I have to declare my ImageView which ViewController it should call.

so my Code is:

```
-(void) initImageViews{
self.navigationItem.title = @"Menu";
UIImage *serviceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Service.png"];
self.serviceImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:serviceImage];
[self.serviceImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 48,48 )];
[self.view addSubview:self.serviceImageView];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

UIImage *industryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Industry.png"];
self.industryImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:industryImage];
[self.industryImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(73,20,48,48)];
[self.view addSubview:industryImageView];
   UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

    [self.industryImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    [self.serviceImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    [self.serviceImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [self.industryImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

 }

    - (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

NSLog(@"Tapped!");

 }

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Service"]) {
    SelectOptionViewController *controller = (SelectOptionViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
}if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Industry"]) {
    SelectOptionViewController *controller = (SelectOptionViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
}
}

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a seague in the storyboard with the identifier.then programatically call a segue like this

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"myidentifier" sender: self];
```

Comment: Okay, but how can I make a difference between my 2 ImageViews? 
e.g. if( image == IndustryViewImage) call View1
     else call View2

Comment: Thanks, now I recognized that singleTap just works for one imageView, so I tried to init and add a new gestureRecognizer but I thinks this couldn't be the right way ??

Answer (score 2):

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:IdentifierForTheSegueiFromStoryBoard sender:nil];
```

EDIT: the seque must exist in the storyboard and must have an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want/need to use segues you could use:

```
if (i want controller A) {
    [self presentViewController:ControllerA animated:YES completion:nil];
} else if (i want controller B) 
    [self presentViewController:ControllerB animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```